# ContextualVersionConflict error Import Google BigQuery in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load csv data from python into big query table following: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#python, so my first step is to import Google Big Query in python as below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

But it throws me the error `ContextualVersionConflict`

```
ContextualVersionConflict: (google-api-core 1.25.1 (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages), Requirement.parse('google-api-core[grpc]!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.*,!=2.4.*,!=2.5.*,!=2.6.*,!=2.7.*,<3.0.0dev,>=1.32.0'), {'google-cloud-bigquery-storage'})
```

My google package versions are:

```
google-api-core           2.10.1                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.33.0                   pyhd3eb1b0_0  
google-auth-oauthlib      0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-bigquery     3.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 2.15.0               pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-core         2.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-storage      2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-crc32c             1.1.2                    py39h9ed2024_0  
google-resumable-media    2.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
googleapis-common-protos  1.56.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pydata-google-auth        1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
```

Has anyone met the same issue before? Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: How did you choose the versions of packages ?

Comment: I didn't choose these versions specifically, I guess when I did pip install, it just automatically installed the latest version for me?

Comment: You did `pip install google-cloud` ? https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/